# My Crystal Report is not getting refreshed while passing parameter?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-8.5, crystal-reports-server

I have created my Crystal Reports using SQL query in Crystal Reports itself, by passing two parameters, i.e, say for eg:- Month & Year.

While I preview the report, I can able to navigate through all pages by passing different parameters and its working fine, but while viewing the report through browser I can't able to view the current report instead is loads the previously generated report, but while I manually make refresh the crystal page in toolbar I can see the current report, even I can't navigate the current report.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the 'Discard Saved Data When Loading Reports' option.

Should be able to find it here:
Right Click/Design/Default Settings/Reporting/Discard Saved Data When Loading Reports

Not sure if that will fix your problem or not but definitely worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

go to file> save data with report.......

I think it will help you

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late for the reply, but I was facing the same problem may be somebody else will go through the same. I applied many hints from different sites including stack-overflow but finally I solved my problem with this code snip..

```
            crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
            crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Thanks!